# MySQL remove distinct unordered tuples

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my result set, I have records such as (a,b), (b,a)
I only need to show distinct pair, not taking into consideration the order.

How would this be achieved from my query?

[image]

Comment: Will you always have a set of 2 unordered pairs?

Comment: @JRD Yes, there will always be the case as shown in the image, set of unordered pairs, where i need to just show a distinct pair.

Comment: In that case, either of the answers below should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `AND A.model != B.model` to `AND A.model < B.model`.

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize to the lower value on the left, and the higher value on the right with

```
select distinct least(A.Model,B.Model), greatest(A.Model,B.Model) ...
```